どうにも、どうにか、いかにも、どうか、どうもの中にパターンが潜在していますか？
いつも（どうにも、どうにか、いかにも、どうか、どうも）という種類の単語を聞いたり読んだりすると、パターンがいかにもあると感じます。
どう思われますか？
具体的に言えば私が話しているパターンは見かけ上共通の語源を持っていて1つの助詞を変えて1つ追加したり2つ追加したりすると意味が異なることを理解したいと思っています

I voted to close. Unfortunately, a question needs to be more specific. If you have doubts about particular phrases, focus the question accordingly.

@sundowner 質問を編集しました

歴史的にはもちろん、これらの単語は関連していますが、結論から言うと、残念ながら現代語ではそれぞれ個別の慣用句となってしまっており、「どうか」「どうも」の一部の意味を除いて、文法的に説明することはできません。
まず、「に」は格助詞であり、今の文法では名詞にしか接続できません。「どう」は副詞のため、現代語では「どう」+「に」という形を作ることは、もはやできません。少し古い時代では「どうに」を現代語の「どのように」 (= in what manner/state/outcome) と同じ意味で使うことができたと思われますが、「どうに」から派生した表現も、もはや「どうにか」「どうにも」「どうにでも」以外の形が存在せず、それぞれ特徴的な意味を持っているので、別々に覚えた方がいいでしょう。
また、「どうに～」以外で「どう」自体に助詞をつけて作れる表現も「どうぞ」「どうも」「どうか」と、述語として使う場合の「どうだ」の活用形しかありません。前の3種類も、「ぞ」「も」「か」は一見すると現代でも使われる助詞ですが、慣用句として使われる場合は、古語の滅んだ意味を引き継いでいるため、今の文法では説明できません。なお、「どうか」は一見「何」→「何か」、「誰」→「誰か」のパターンに似ていますが、同じ意味は表しません。「どう」から不定表現を作りたい場合は場合に応じて「何かの方法」「何らかの状況」などと言い換える必要があります。
ちなみに、「どうか」「どうも」の規則的な用法とは、次のようなものです。

昼は食堂で食べたらどうか。 You might as well have lunch in cafeteria.
（どう "how (about)" + 疑問の「か」）
クレーンがなければどうもできない。 We can't be of any help without a crane.
（どう "how (into what)" + も "even"）

最後に、「いかにも」の「いかに」は「どう」のより古い言い方ですが、この関連表現も現代語では「いかなる」（=どんな）「いかに」（=どれほど、どうやって）の2種類しか生き残っていません。そして「いかにも」は「どう」の系統のどれとも異なる純粋な慣用句になってしまっています。

簡潔で要約された回答をありがとうございます。実際、言葉や慣用句の語源を知ることは言語の直感を養うのに役立ちます。
